# I was hoping for some help debugging this ruby script. I'm having trouble using the output function from outside the class

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods, static, static-methods

I'm having an issue with calling the method output statically from outside of the class. Specifically calling the output method on the object znumber at the end of the code. I get this error: 
undefined method `output' for #<WeightedScore:0x007ffb3815d840>
(repl):58:in`'
(repl):9:in `'

My Code:

```html
class WeightedScore
  def initialize(scores)
    @names = ['Amy', 'Annie', 'Fred', 'Marge', 'Tim', 'Sarah', 'John', 'Elise',
         'Andy', 'Ellen']
    @emails = ['amy@example.com', 'annie@example.com', 'fred@example.com',
          'marge@example.com', 'tim@example.com', 'sarah@example.com',
          'john@example.com', 'elise@example.com', 'andy@example.com',
          'ellen@example.com']
    @scores = scores
  end

  def weighted_score(score)
      if score == 0
        return 0
      else
        return (215 + average_score) / score
  end

  def average_score
    score = 0
    i = 1
    @scores.each do |score|
        score += score
        i = i + 1
    end
    return score / i
  end

  def output
    i = 0
    while i < 10
      name = @names[i]
        i = i + 1
        line_string = i.to_s
          line_string << ". #{@name[i]}, #{@emails[i]}, W = #{weighted_score(@scores[i]).to_s}"
      if @scores[i] > 5
           puts line_string
      end
    end
  end
end
# START

# these ten scores correspond, in order, with the names of test taker
scores = [2, 5, -2, 9, 0, 23, -8, 7, 1, 4]

# instantiate the class with the scores
znumber = WeightedScore.new(scores)
# print out the names, emails and weighted scores
znumber.output
end
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Your method says `def self.output`. What happens if you change it to `def output`? It's pretty hard to work with a PNG. You should paste in your code letting us know where line 58 is, and also explain what you have done to try to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for responding! It still doesn't work when I do that. I've tried changing it to an instance and static method, but it still wont work. I think its because I am trying to call a static method on an instance of the class, and I'm not sure how to get this to work.

Comment: I'll have to look at it further now that you've pasted in some code (thanks!), but this is an instance method, not a class/static method. Note that the method is using instance variables that are specific to an instantiated WeightedScore object.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a few things, but I'm not completely sure what you expect for output.

The biggest problem, I think, was that in the `weighted_score` method you did not end your `if-else` with an `end`. I put an `end` in there and removed the final `end` from your code sample. In the `output` method you referred to `@name[i]` instead of `@names[i]`, and the location of the incrementer for your while loop was probably not where it was intended to be.

See if this works for you. Bedtime for me.

```
 class WeightedScore
  def initialize(scores)
    @names = ['Amy', 'Annie', 'Fred', 'Marge', 'Tim', 'Sarah', 'John', 'Elise',
         'Andy', 'Ellen']
    @emails = ['amy@example.com', 'annie@example.com', 'fred@example.com',
          'marge@example.com', 'tim@example.com', 'sarah@example.com',
          'john@example.com', 'elise@example.com', 'andy@example.com',
          'ellen@example.com']
    @scores = scores
  end

  def weighted_score(score)
      if score == 0
        return 0
      else
        return (215 + average_score) / score
      end
  end

  def average_score
    score = 0
    i = 1
    @scores.each do |score|
        score += score
        i = i + 1
    end
    return score / i
  end

  def output
    i = 0
    while i < 10
      name = @names[i]
        line_string = i.to_s
          line_string << ". #{@names[i]}, #{@emails[i]}, W = #{weighted_score(@scores[i]).to_s}"
      if @scores[i] > 5
           puts line_string
      end
      i = i + 1
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The "output" method is a class method, and the "znumber" is a WeightedScore instance variable. You should remove the "self." in the "def self.output" to make the output an instance method.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for responding! I've tried doing that, but I still haven't gotten it to work yet

Comment: Buddy, Firstly, you should an "end" in the weighted_score method.
Secondly, the "@name" should be "@names" in the output method.
Thirdly, there still a mistake with "(215 + average_score) / score" which you should let "score" can't be zero. 
Finally, the "@scores[i] > 5" would trigger an error if the @scores[i] is nil.

Comment: Additionally, remove the "end" at the last line.